# simplifying integral equation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am working on some problems from a book.
I want to know how equation

$ s[Y] = 2 \int  ^{Z}_{0}    z  (\dfrac {1} {4z^2}  (Y')^2  - w^2Y^2 ) dz   $

Where $ Z = X^{1/2} $

simplifies to this one ?

$ s[Y]= \dfrac{1}{2} \int  ^{Z}_{0}  (\dfrac{1}{z}(Y')^2   - 4zw^2Y^2) dz $

how 2 outside of $\int$ sign became 1/2 and how second term inside $\int$ has 4 now ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply everything by $1=\frac{4}{4}$ where you multiply by 4 inside the integral and by $\frac{1}{4}$ outside of it.

Comment: how did we decide that out side of $\int$ is going to be multiplied by $\frac{1}{4}$